# Como fazer uma condição com numero mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Oi estou fazendo tipo um banco virtual em uma parte tem fazer o deposito,o usuario tem o dinheiro em carteira por exemplo.

Eu tenho 500 reais na carteira

porém se eu colocar qualquer valor acima de 500 ele deposita na conta do banco e eu queria que o usuario so pudesse colocar o valor maximo que ele tem em carteira

Codigo para enviar o valor

```
<center>
    <select name="id">

<?php
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE id=1";
    $mostra_dados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostra_dados)){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?><?php echo $rows_cursos['usuario']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: coloca o que vc ja tentou ai

Comment: Post atualizado ele esta assim no momento

Comment: Ainda está meio confuso, onde vc quer definir esse limite?

Comment: Beleza, ai ele envia o valor para essa mesma pagina que fará o deposito, esse código está onde?

Comment: Eu quero colocar o limite quando ele for enviar por exemplo ele tem 100 reais na carteira quando ele digitar no campo pra depositar por exemplo 500 reais ele nao vai conseguir entendeu?

Comment: quando ele aperta o botao enviar o valor no momento ele ta sendo redirecionado para a pagina setting que faz o update tirando o valor digitado da carteira dele e adicionando ao banco.

$recebe_dados = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
 
$result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id";

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei o campo `max` no `<input>` que ele digita o valor com o valor que tem com conta (você altera o nome dos campos que forem necessários), que vai limitar até à quantia que ele tem em conta, no update você faz uma reconfirmação se os valores estão de acordo antes de executar o update.

```
<?php
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE id=1";
    $mostra_dados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostra_dados)){ 
        $dinheiroEmConta=$rows_cursos['dinheiro'];
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows_cursos['usuario']; ?></option>
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="valor" max="<?php echo $dinheiroEmConta; ?>">
 <?php 
    }
?>
```

Esse trecho deve vir dps da parte em que ocorre o `SELECT` que gera o `$result_usuario`, para que possa criar a variável `$dinheiroEmConta` que adicionei no bloco de códigos acima, e então fazer isso:

```
if((isset($_POST['dinheiro']))&&(!empty($_POST['dinheiro']))){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro'];
    if($dinheiro <= $dinheiroEmConta){

        $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
        $_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;

        $recebe_dados = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro', depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
        $result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: voce pode me ajuda na reafirmação do update

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];


 
 $dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro'];


 $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

 $_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;



 $recebe_dados = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
 
 $result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id";
 $recebe_dados2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";

Comment: me ajuda porfavor eu ainda nao consegui ta ficando negativo ainda

Comment: Ajudo, mas preciso de algumas informações

Comment: QUAL ?me ajuda pf

Comment: Acho que agora vc consegue, qualquer coisa me avisa, posso demorar um pouquinho, mas responderei

Comment: Cara eu nao consegui sinceramente olha

Comment: Parte de enviar ficou assim


<?php
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE id=1";
    $mostra_dados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostra_dados)){ 
        $dinheiroEmConta=$rows_cursos['dinheiro'];
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows_cursos['usuario']; ?></option>
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="dinheiro" max="<?php echo $dinheiroEmConta; ?>">
 <?php 
    }
 
 
?>

Comment: no update assim 
$result_usuario = "SELECT dinheiro FROM usuarios WHERE id='". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
if((isset($_POST['dinheiro']))&&(!empty($_POST['dinheiro']))){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro'];
    if($dinheiro <= $dinheiroEmConta){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
    $_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;
$recebe_dados = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro', depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
$result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id"; 
}
}

Comment: agora ele nem diminui o valor digitado e nem aumenta o valor pro banco

Comment: acusa algum erro pelo menos?

Comment: nao olha como esta a pasta settings que faz o update

[link](http://prntscr.com/ka2kzz)

e a parte do input

[link](http://prntscr.com/ka2lo6)

Comment: Ta muito confuso, tem query q nem existe, tipo `SELECT usuarios SET dinheiro`

Comment: como pode me ajudar?