# Como fazer condição com numero msql

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Pessoal preciso muito de ajuda eu tenho um input para a pessoa fazer uma transferência em dinheiro mas se essa pessoa tiver 30 reais de dinheiro e ela digitar um valor de 100 reais para fazer a transferencia ela vai ficar com saldo -100 eu so quero que ela possa transferir o maximo de dinheiro que estiver no banco de dados

Codigo que eu uso para fazer a transferencia do usuario para o banco

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="thee-tab">
    <p><form method="POST" action="?pagina=setting">

<center>
    <select name="id">

<?php
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE id=1";
    $mostra_dados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostra_dados)){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows_cursos['usuario']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>

Dinheiro: <input type="text" name="dinheiro" max="<?php echo $rows_cursos['dinheiro']; ?>">
```

Codigo que eu uso para fazer o update do banco de dados diminuindo o valor digitado do usuario e adicionando a conta no banco

```
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro']; 
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
$_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro; 

$recebe_dados1 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
$recebe_dados2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id"; 
$recebe_dados3 = "UPDATE usuarios SET depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
```

Comment: Sugiro editar a pergunta usando a pontuação de forma apropriada. Sua questão está ilegível.

Comment: Se o usuario tiver 100 reais entao ele so pode depositar no maximo 100 reais entendeu? no meu caso se a pessoa tiver 100 reais e ela fazer uma transferencia de 500 reais o saldo dela vai ficar -400

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer uma condição com numero mysql php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316985/como-fazer-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-numero-mysql-php)

Answer (score 2):

**FORMA EXPLICADA**

Simples, basta fazer uma validação antes do `UPDATE`, sobre o valor informado pelo usuário. Mais ou menos dessa forma:

**Inicio do seu código PHP colocado na pergunta**

```
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro']; 
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
//$_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;  deixa essa parte para depois de validar
```

**Validação (Solução)**

```
// faz a busca pelas informações do usuário que irá fazer a transferência
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM 'usuarios' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// verifica se o dinheiro que ele informou para o deposito é maior 
// do que o valor que ele possui em banco
// EDIT: Tinha esquecido do ";"
if ($dinheiro > $rows['dinheiro'])
    $dinheiro = $rows['dinheiro'];
```

Com a condição, se ele passar um valor maior do que ele possui, o valor será alterado para o valor máximo que ele possui (que está cadastrado no banco). Após feita essa validação, ai sim, você pode salvar o valor do dinheiro na sessão:

```
$_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;
```

**Final do seu código PHP colocado na pergunta**

```
$recebe_dados1 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
$recebe_dados2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id"; 
$recebe_dados3 = "UPDATE usuarios SET depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
```

---

**FORMA SIMPLES (APENAS CÓDIGO)**

```
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro']; 
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
//$_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;  deixa essa parte para depois de validar
// faz a busca pelas informações do usuário que irá fazer a transferência
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM 'usuarios' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// verifica se o dinheiro que ele informou para o deposito é maior 
// do que o valor que ele possui em banco
// EDIT: Tinha esquecido do ";"
if ($dinheiro > $rows['dinheiro'])
    $dinheiro = $rows['dinheiro'];

$_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;

$recebe_dados1 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
$recebe_dados2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = $id"; 
$recebe_dados3 = "UPDATE usuarios SET depositado = depositado +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
```

Comment: traduz porfavor kkk sou novato em php onde tenho que colocar oque nos codigos

Comment: adicionei na resposta o código como deve ficar.

Comment: isso deve ficar na parte de cima do input no campo que ele digita o valor ou na pagina quando o valor é enviado?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: se você só copiou o código, eu esqueci um `;` que pode ter causado esse erro.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: me ajuda porfavor